# Missing project references on fresh visual studio install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Just installed Visual Studio 2015 on my new laptop and cloned a project. It's telling me there is missing references.  I have this project running fine on 4 other computers all with similar setups which is basically Windows 10 and a default installation of Visual Studio 2015 Community. I can do a fresh clone, press play and everything runs fine on those computers.

On the computers where the references work the missing references all seem to be somewhere under the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\'. On my new laptop the path for these missing references is blank but they do exist when I browse to that folder on the laptop.

A couple examples of the references in the csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked where the references point to in the .csproj file?

Comment: The project file has no paths for most of them, looks like there are hintpaths for 3. Updated the question with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will be useful to many people but after trying a dozen different solutions I installed VS **2013** Community.  Whatever that installation did fixed something so that the references show up now and I can run the project in VS **2015** Community or 2013 if I cared to.

The solution file was originally created in VS 2012 and you can still see that in the file.